# Create a 2D array with a nested loop

Tags: python

The following code

```
n = 3
matrix = [[0] * n] * n
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        matrix[i][j] = i * n + j 
print(matrix)
```

prints

```
[[6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8]]
```

but what I expect is

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this:

```
>>> matrix = [[0] * 3] * 3
>>> [x for x in matrix]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> [id(x) for x in matrix]
[32484168, 32484168, 32484168]
>>>
```

Three rows but only one object.

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) especially Note 2 about the `s * n` operation.

Fix:

```
>>> m2= [[0] * 3 for i in xrange(5)]
>>> [id(x) for x in m2]
[32498152, 32484808, 32498192, 32499952, 32499872]
>>>
```

**Update:** Here are some samples of code that gets an answer *simply* (i.e. without `iter()`):

```
>>> nrows = 2; ncols = 4
>>> zeroes = [[0 for j in xrange(ncols)] for i in xrange(nrows)]
>>> zeroes
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> ap = [[ncols * i + j for j in xrange(ncols)] for i in xrange(nrows)]
>>> ap
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>>
```

Comment: The docs says "...This often haunts new Python programmers...". True! But why this feature can be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `matrix[0][0] = 0` after that. Notice it now becomes:

```
[[0, 7, 8], [0, 7, 8], [0, 7, 8]]
```

So it's changing all three at the same time.

Read this: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/58916

That seems to explain it.

Comment: Thanks Mk12 for the link. And I have the same question: whether this is a "feature" of Python or a "bug."?

Comment: It isn't something I expected, that's for sure. But it makes sense.

Comment: @user949952: The docs (see my answer) say that it takes a shallow copy of the sequence. So it's a feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> it = iter(range(9))
>>> [[next(it) for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

just replace `3` with `n` and `9` with `n**2`

Also (just answer the "why?"), you're making copies of the same list with multiplication and, therefore, modifying one of them will modify all of them.